# How do I open a directory in a new tab from angular 8 using the directory's absolute path?

Tags: html, angular, web, frontend, angular8

I want to view some directory in a new tab from angular 8 using the absolute directory path.

Right now I'm trying the following

html

```
<a (click)="goToLink()">click to see directory</a>
```

ts

```
goToLink()  {
    window.open("/directory/path");
  }
```

but this open a new tab with the url 
"http://localhost:4200/directory/path"

which just takes me to 
"http://localhost:4200"
my app homepage

Answer (score 0):

Add "_blank" to your window.open call.

```
goToLink()  {
    window.open("/directory/path", "_blank");
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it gives the same result as not adding "_blank"

Answer (score 0):

Just add an appropriate route for `directory/path` to your `Route` config:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: 'directory/path', component: DirectoryComponent }
];
```

The `DirectoryComponent` should be your custom component, that will be opened by clicking on the `directory/path` link. If you already have a path in `Route` config, then the problem might be in `guards`.

Comment: Isn't that just moving the goalposts?
I would need to show the directory contents in ```DirectoryComponent``` then, which is the initial problem I'm looking to solve.